# asp.net - do AsyncPostBack using js

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-ajax

I've spent almost 3 hours for the following case:

- I want to trigger an AsyncPostBack from JavaScript but to be able to send same parameter also because I need it on the server side.

I've tried a lot of situations but I am unable to find a clear example.

I have an update panel and when I am pressing a specific image button inside it, some popup is displayed. (the popup is hidden initially, and when the request is done, the `display:none` is removed=> it appears fine)

```
 function BeginRequestHandler(sender, args) {
    }
    function EndRequestHandler(sender, args) {
        document.getElementById('popup').style.display = '';
        document.getElementById('overlay').style.display = '';

    }
```

Well, the issue is that I need to make a js function to do the asyncPostBack because *this js function will be called from a flash control when doing click on some portion of that control, so I want to simulate my click on the image.* (because doing click this popup is displayed as you see above)

The issue is that I am not able to find anywhere such an example. **This js function will receive a parameter so when I do the postback I want to be able to get that parameter on the server side.** (this parameters seems to be the main problem =- how I send it to the server when I am doing postback?).

Sorry if I was not very clear, but can you give me some documentation for this or example?

Thanks a lot!

**UPDATE:**
Please note that the first case I've already done, using an ImageButton in my UpdatePanel:

```
<asp:ImageButton ID="lnkDetails" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Logo") %>'
                            AlternateText='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Name") %>' OnCommand="lnkDetails_Command"
                            CommandArgument='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "TenantID") %>' Text="Click">
                        </asp:ImageButton></li>
```

What I only need is to "simulate" this click, using a javascript to make the async post back (because when I will call from flash, flash control will call my js method for postback)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work quite well:

```
<asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton1" runat="server" OnClientClick='return doSomething(<%#Eval("SomeValue")%>);' />
```

**EDIT:** Try wrapping your JavaScript function with this:

```
Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_pageLoaded(function () {
    doSomething = function(argument){
        __doPostBack("<%=ImageButton1.ClientID%>", argument);
        return true; //don't know if you need this
    }
});
```

**EDIT**: Check your `ScriptManager` and make sure that `EnablePartialRendering` is set to true.

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" EnablePartialRendering="true" ... />
```

In the code-behind:

```
protected override void RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler source, string eventArgument)
{
    //call the RaisePostBack event 
    base.RaisePostBackEvent(source, eventArgument);

    if (source == ImageButton1)
    {
        string arg = eventArgument;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! but is there any way to avoid a full refresh of the page? Because I've tried doPostBack and the whole page is refreshed...

Comment: Hmm... it should be asynchronous since the ImageButton is in an update panel. Can you post your markup?

Comment: Thanks James, please see my update. Basically, what you put here I've already done. Now I only want to make a js method to simulate all this stuff (do asyncPostBack, send a specific param and for me to be able to catch that param on the server side).

Comment: One small issue? Can you tell me the `sender` in the method where I have to declare?

Comment: Sorry, it should be `source` not `sender`. My mistake.

Comment: It works, the single issue is that argument is empty; I've changed it to: `OnClientClick='return doSomething("test_arg");'` but in the server method, the argument is empty...

Comment: Are you passing the argument into the `__doPostBack(sender, arg)` method?

Comment: Yes, I did not modified that. All it's like you put here except OnClick where I put "test_arg"...

Comment: Try removing the return statement, or set it to return false. I don't think you need it. I think that's probably throwing it off.

Comment: Just removed from both places, and still argument is empty. Even if I hardcode it directly in the javasscript function...

Comment: Which of the changes got it to start working? Was it the `EnablePartialRendering` or the wrapper around the function? Can you try removing that wrapper and see if it makes a difference?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4452/discussion-between-cristian-boariu-and-james-johnson)

Answer (score 2):

To initiate an async postback from javascript:

```
__doPostBack(target,args)
```

target is the UniqueID of the UpdatePanel you want to target. Usually it works fine to just pass an empty string (will refresh all auto-updating panels).

The 2nd parameter is arguments that you can use for whatever you want.

Both will be available to you on the server:

```
Request.Form["__EVENTTARGET"]
Request.Form["__EVENTARGUMENT"]
```